# Ionic 3 website in Iframe focus on input causing page redirect

Tags: android, iframe, keyboard, web, ionic3

I have successfully used an external website as an iframe in ionic 3 app. 
I am using below code in home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  url: any;
 constructor(private sanitize: DomSanitizer, public navCtrl: NavController) 
{}
  urlpaste(){
    this.url = "someurl";
    return this.sanitize.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.url);
  }
}
```

home.html:

```
<iframe style="height: 100vh; width: 100%;"  [src]="urlpaste()" name="iframe_a"></iframe>
```

Website is working fine in android (I have not tested for IOS) except when I focus on any input mobile keyboard displays for a while and then page redirects to home page of the website. Can someone please help me to resolve this. I have searched a lot on Google but I could not find out the reason of this strange behavior.